# CSS cursor property not working properly when hovering over a link

Tags: css, html, sass

I'm using the following code to change my website's cursor (SASS):

```
body {
  cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), auto;
  a {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
      cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), pointer;
      color: black;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Chrome as my browser, and for some reason, no matter what I try, I keep seeing this jitter happening when I hover on an `<a>` tag:

[image: An example of the jitter]

I have a suspicion that Chrome's default cursor is causing this but I can't quite figure it out.
Is there a way solve this jitter?

Comment: I don't know that this will fix it, but you might move `cursor` into the main body of `a`'s css rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `cursor` outside of the `:hover` pseudo-selector